# Совместимость версий Python и Django для существующего проекта

Tags: python, django

Программа создана на версиях: Python 3.8.6. и Django 3.1.2. Могу ли установить последние версии на новом компьютере или нужно использовать те же?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос широкий и требует детальной проработки относительно версии `django`. Если обратиться к документации [то можно увидеть](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django), что сам `django` не очень зависим от версии python.

Вы указали, что используете `django 3.1.2`. Из приведенной выше ссылки становится понятно, что максимальная версия Python будет 3.9.

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/#official-releases) `django` говорит:

> A.B is the feature release version number. Each version will be mostly backwards compatible with the previous release. Exceptions to this rule will be listed in the release notes.

Каждая версия, главным образом, обратно совместима с предыдущими релизами. **Исключения, как правило, можно найти в примечаниях к выпуску**. (ВАЖНО! читайте изменения в документации для [django 3.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.2/))

То есть в вашем случае `django` можно обновить до версии 3.2 без пляски с бубнами и почти без риска. А данная версия совместима с python 3.10.

Релизы патчей (3я цифра в номере версии) совместима на 100% с предыдущей.

Заключение: установка на `django 3.2` и `python 3.10` должна пройти безболезненно.

PS

Я бы рискнул и жахнул бы новые версии на все со старта (естественно, на тесте). Потратил бы час времени, чтобы понять работает или нет. А затем бы уже делал выводы.

Comment: Проект на Django 3.1.X может не работать на 3.2.X и выше без внесения изменений, так как там были сделаны небольные изменения по админке как минимум. Можете почитать в изменениях версий на оф сайте

Comment: Надежнее будет на локалке обновиться до нужных версий, проверить функционал, а потом уже если все ок - обновлять на сервере

Comment: Да я в принципе и подразумевал такую логику. Выделю, что надо читать доку

Comment: Дмитрий, Спасибо большое за ваш ответ. Я вначале установил последние версии, но запустить не удалось. Изменил версию Django и все заработало.

Comment: На здоровье, поздравляю. К таким задачам индивидуальный подход